# Usar Javascript para lista de iframes

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando `iframes` para um portal, tive que usa-lo chamando por `id` para resolver um problema anterior.
O problema agora é que não consigo criar uma lista de `iframes` no javascript, somente consigo criar uma `id` com a `src`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou usando assim, mais somente armazeno essa `src`, não consigo armazenar mais.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("id_Iframe").src="LINK_IFRAME";
}
```

Comment: Tem como dar mais detalhes? O que quer dizer com lista de IFRAMES? Pq no meu entendimento basta replicar os códigos para ter vários.

Comment: Passei batido no ; pra fechar cada linha. kkkk vou testar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente eu estava dando bobeira. Faltava fechar com ;; para o próximo código:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("id_Iframe").src="LINK_IFRAME";;
document.getElementById("id_Iframe2").src="LINK_IFRAME";;
}
```

Depois e so chamar pelo `id` no html.

Editada:

Solução muito melhor, que resolveu meu problema, e o `iframe` so abre quando se abre o `modal` e quando fecha o `modal` ele descarrega o `src`.

```
   $('#MyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#MyModal iframe').attr('src','LINK EXTERNO OU INTERNO');
  })
   $('#MyModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#MyModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
  })
```

Muito bom pra o site não ficar pesado carregando os `iframes` antes de abri-ló

Comment: Ele até pode funcionar porém o correto é uma apenas 1 ponto e virgula (;) por linha.

Comment: Somente ; não tá funcionando.  Eu chamo a src pela id em um modal.

Comment: Amigo, repeti vários. Mais ele começa a fazer cache no navegador. Ai como os iframe são do mesmo site, os elementos dos iframes param de funcionar. Como posso contornar?